# Como modificar datos obtenidos y mostrarlo en datatable (ajax)

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatables

Tengo una pregunta respecto al plugin datatables, lo estoy usando en un proyecto laravel 8, antes tenia una tabla donde traia datos y los mostraba acompañados de texto, tambien tenia un dato tipo integer que al traerlo lo formateaba para mostrarlo como moneda, asi:

```
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($products as $product)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
            <td >{{$product->current_stock}} de {{$product->stock}}</td>
            <td class="{{$product->status_stock >= 0 && $product->status_stock <= 20 ? 'bg-danger text-white' : ($product->status_stock > 21 &&$product->status_stock < 50 ? 'bg-warning text-dark' : '')}}">El producto se encuentra con {{$product->status_stock}}% del stock original</td>
            @inject('priceService', 'App\Services\PriceService')
            <td>{{$priceService->getPriceFormat($product->price)}}</td>
            <td>{{$product->category->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$product->status}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{route('products.edit', $product)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">Editar</a>
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-sm detail_button" product-id="{{$product->id}}">Ver detalles</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

logre traer los datos con json de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                                $('#dataTable').DataTable({
                                    "language": {
                                        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página",
                                        "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron registros - disculpa",
                                        "info": "Mostrando la pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                                        "infoEmpty": "No records available",
                                        "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros totales)",
                                        "search": "Buscar:",
                                        'paginate': {
                                            'next': 'Siguiente',
                                            'previous' : 'Anterior'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "ajax": "{{route('products.list_json')}}",
                                    "columns":[
                                        {data: 'name'},
                                        {data: 'current_stock'},
                                        {data: 'status_stock'},
                                        {data: 'price'},
                                        {data: 'category.name'},
                                        {data: 'status'},
                                        
                                        
                                    ],
                                });
                            });
```

Pero necesito dejarlos como los estoy mostrando arriba, en la documentacion solo encontre como añadir columnas extras pero no encontre como modificar las que estoy trayendo, es posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que si quieres modificar los datos que traes, puedes hacerlo dentro de DataTable({}) en el [fnCreatedRow](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnCreatedRow), pensemos por ejemplo que quieres modificar el precio y sumarle un 10% adicional. (La columna price es la columna 3 de la tabla).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página",
            "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron registros - disculpa",
            "info": "Mostrando la pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "No records available",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros totales)",
            "search": "Buscar:",
            'paginate': {
                'next': 'Siguiente',
                'previous' : 'Anterior'
            }
        },
        "ajax": "{{route('products.list_json')}}",
        "columns":[
            {data: 'name'},
            {data: 'current_stock'},
            {data: 'status_stock'},
            {data: null},
            {data: 'category.name'},
            {data: 'status'},
        ],
        "fnCreatedRow": function(nRow,aData,iDataIndex) {
            var new_price = parseFloat(aData.price) + 0.1 * parseFloat(aData.price);
            $('td:eq(3)',nRow).html(new_price);
        }
    });
});
```

Este caso, podríamos realizarlo desde la consulta SQL correspondiente, pero de esta misma manera puedes añadir elementos HTML como botones en una columna determinada.

Answer (score 0):

Puede dejar la cabecera de la tabla con HTML fijo que contiene los nombres de las columnas que está esperando, los nombres de los atributos data de columns, representan el nombre de las columnas en SQL. Otra opcion, es que desde la consulta SQL agruegue un alias a cada columna al hacer el select, de esta manera en data cambiaría el nombre de las columnas a las especificadas en el alias. Esas dos opciones pueden ser.

Comment: Hola, no entiendo tu respuesta, estoy intentando modificar un dato obtenido con ajax y mostrarlo en el datatable